# AWS Signature Version 4 IAM authorization

Tags: apex, community, salesforce1-app, rest, certification

If we want to use AWS Signature Version 4 IAM authorization to add some security controls to some functions in our AWS API,

so only a salesforce user can use these particular functions.

Do salesforce support AWS Signature Version 4 IAM authorization when calling out to REST API services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salesforce now has native support for AWS v4 signature generation.

Create a new Named Credential for the service endpoint, for example:

- Name: `S3`
- URL: `https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
- Identity Type: `Named Principal`
- Auth Protocol: `AWS Signature V4`
- AWS Access Key ID: `[your key here]`
- AWS Secret Access Key: `[your secret here]`
- AWS Region: `us-east-1`
- AWS Service: `s3`

Then send an HTTP request according to the API docs, eg:

```
String url = 'callout:S3/bucket/file.ext';

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setEndpoint(url);
HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
```

Keys are generated from AWS Console > Security Credentials > Access Keys

[image]

Comment: where are the definitions for canonicalMethodFor, canonicalUriFor, canonicalQueryStringFor, canonicalHeadersFor, signedHeadersFor, hexEncodedHash ? also could you probide a sample of the params map? for instance to list bucket