# AWS PUT Request from VisualForce

Tags: apex, visualforce, amazon-s3

I have created a Named Credential within SF that stores the Authentication information for our AmazonS3 instance.

Here is the Named Credential Setup
[image]

We have code that is working when the AmazonS3 credentials are stored directly within the VisualForce page, but, for obvious reasons, this is not ideal.

The idea is the VF page takes an input of images from a user and uploads them to AmazonS3, creating its own folder based on the UniqueID entered by the user.

How can I have the VisualForce page access the information from the Named Credential easily for a PUT request?

I have reviewed SalesForce documentation and believe I am just missing a small piece, but cannot figure out what that is. Any straightforward assistance is appreciated in this matter.

Here is my custom Apex Code:

```
public class AmazonS3{
    public string AmazonS3Request { get; set; }
    public static void AmazonS3Request() {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('PUT');
        request.setEndpoint('callout:AWSS3');
        HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
        System.debug(response.getStatusCode());
        System.debug(response.getBody());
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm referencing it in the VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="AmazonS3" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
```

Here is how I'm calling AmazonS3Request in my VF page

```
<input type="button" class="top-buffer" value="Submit All Images" onclick="{!AmazonS3Request} s3upload()"/>
```

I am getting this:

```
HTTP Header Authorization=Not Set 
and a 403 Error.
```

Here is the full VF page - As you can see, the bucket is configured at the beginning of the Script.

```
<apex:page controller="AmazonS3" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.styleForImageUpload}"/>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.839.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    
//Bucket Configurations
var bucketName = "salesforce-simplyhome-images";
var bucketRegion = "us-east-1";

            var s3 = new AWS.S3({
                apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
                params: {Bucket: bucketName}
        });
        
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newRow = row.insertCell(i);
    newRow.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    newRow.childNodes[0].value = "";
  }
}
function deleteRow(row) {
  var table = document.getElementById("data");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  if (rowCount > 1) {
    var rowIndex = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("data").deleteRow(rowIndex);
  }
  else {
    alert("Please specify at least one value.");
  }
}


async function s3upload() {
  var uniqueId,
  element = document.getElementById("uniqueId").value;
  if (element != "") {
      uniqueId = element;
  }
  else {
       alert("Please specify a Unique ID. This has been emailed to you.");
       return;
  }
  var updatedFileName = document.getElementsByClassName("updatedFileName");  
  var files = document.getElementsByClassName("uploadFile");
  function toArray(arr) {
    return [].slice.call(arr);
  }
  var files_arr = toArray(files).filter(v => v.files[0] != null);
  var actual_files = new Array();
  var errors_arr = new Array();
  files_arr.forEach(function callback(file_obj,i){
    actual_files[i] = file_obj.files[0]
  })   
  var updated_file_names_arr = toArray(updatedFileName);
  var image_count = actual_files.length;
  var final_image_index = image_count-1;
  var success_count = 0;
  var error_count = 0;
  var final_message = "";
  for ( var i = 0; i <= final_image_index; i++ ) {
    var file = actual_files[i];
    var fileName = updatedFileName[i].value; 
    var filePath = uniqueId + '/' + fileName + '.jpg';
    var fileUrl = 'https://' + bucketRegion + '.amazonaws.com/' + uniqueId + '/' +  filePath;
    var params = { Body: file, Key: filePath };
   try { 
      var result = await s3.upload(params).promise()
      console.log(result)
      var upload_success = true
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      var upload_success = false
    };
    if (upload_success == true) {
      success_count++;
    } else {
      error_count++;
      errors_arr.push(fileName);
    };
    var total_count = success_count + error_count;
    var uploaded_percent = 100 * total_count / image_count;
    document.getElementById("progress").value = uploaded_percent;
    if (uploaded_percent == 100) {
      var final_message = success_count + " images uploaded successfully. ";
      if (error_count != 0) {
          final_message += "Errors encountered uploading: ";
          final_message += errors_arr;
      };
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert(final_message);
      },5);
    };
  };
};
  
</script>
<br></br><br></br><br></br>
<div id="main">
  <h1>Please Upload Home Images</h1>
  <table id="header" class="data-table data-table-horizontal data-table-highlight">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> Please Enter Unique ID (Emailed to you)</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="uniqueId" value="" placeholder="Enter Unique ID" required="true"/></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="data" class="data-table data-table-horizontal data-table-highlight">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      
 </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>    
  <tr>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="top-buffer" onclick="addRow('data')" />
  </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <div class="pull-center">
<input type="button" class="top-buffer" value="Submit All Images" onclick="{!AmazonS3Request} s3upload()"/>
    </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <progress id="progress" max='100' value='0'></progress>
   
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </apex:page>
```

I've been getting redirected [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115139/aws-signature-version-4-iam-authorization), BUT THIS IS NOT HELPFUL. My previous question was closed, stating this was a solution, but it does not address the issue I'm having.

Thank you for any assistance here.

Comment: it would depend on how you authenticate to S3, is it basic authentication? oauth? credentials in the header?, etc. Do you have in the named credential ´AWSS3´ the full url (final endpoint)?

Comment: @SergioAlcocer - I believe it is basic authentication - Within the named credential, 'AWSS3', the URL listed is - https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: @SergioAlcocer - Do you have any recommendations here?

Comment: Have you set-up the named credential with the Named Principal with the correct user/pass ?

Comment: @SergioAlcocer - Yes, I've made sure this is accurate

Comment: @AlexisFrisch, can you add to your question the options you selected for your Named Credential?   Maybe take a screenshot after taking create to obscure sensitive information.    The `403` is saying the request `Authorization` header is not set.  The Named Credential should set this if configured and referenced properly.   I think you should be able to do System.debug on the request and response to debug the request header to verify what is actually sent in the header.

Comment: @ScottPelak - This has been added to the question above

Comment: Have you tried to change Authentication Protocol to Password Authentication? Instead AWS Signature Version 4.

Comment: Jeferson, AWS doesn't use simple Password authentification, they use their special thing (i.e. AWS signature), from what I remember it is 2 step hashing

Comment: here is related question, you migth want to check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264703/aws-signature-version-4-using-named-credentials

Comment: it says about bucket URL, have you used the same URL for your Visualforce testing?

Comment: @ytiq - I have added the bucketname to the URL in the Named credential, as listed in the doc you shared - This did not have any effect on resolving the error

Comment: @alexis I see that you have outbound connection, do you happen to know if you can select something at that option? Maybe there is some network restriction.

Comment: I also noticed that the `setEndpoint` is pointing to the root of S3, not any bucket, plus it is not sending anything on the body at the code provided.

Comment: In the backend, Named Credentials are a safe place to store secrets + it sets some headers + endpoint for you automatically.   Have you tried constructing your `HttpRequest` and manually set endpoint + headers to verify you are connecting successfully?  Then you can work backwards to make sure you set up your Named Credential properly.   As noted above, your `HttpRequest` endpoint resolves to just `https://s3.us-east.1.amazonaws.com/`.  Don't you need a path to your bucket?

Comment: @AlexisFrisch Please show us the VF code where you call AmazonS3Request().

Comment: @FooBar - I have added this - It is being called upon the Submit button click

Comment: @JefersonChaves - I have uploaded all of my VF page code - the bucket is configured at the beginning of the Script

Comment: @ScottPelak - I have uploaded all of my VF page code - the bucket is configured at the beginning of the Script

Comment: here is a reference to API call you want https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html, you need to use Bucket name in your URL and maybe some additional parameters that you want, since you are using SDK in VF, SDK does some work for you

Comment: @ytiq - I have added the bucket name to the URL of the named credential, and am meeting the same error - Do you have more specifc advice? The provided documentation is not clear to me

Comment: Try getting some files first (to make sure it's working) , because for PUT you need to set Body

Comment: As @ytiq is saying, you need to set a body for the HttpRequest since it's a PUT call with [setBody](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_System_HttpRequest_setBody) which will probably be a JSON string.   e.g. `request.setBody(JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object> { 'key' => 'value' }));`.   Use the API specification to see what needs to be in the body of your calls.

Comment: Actually, it seems like the [AWS Signature Version 4](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_define.htm&type=5#content) Authentication Protocol should fill out (most of) the HttpRequest Header and possibly the Body for you.  You'd need to confirm from the API specification if you need more to add more information in the Body.  If so, you can [merge fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm).

Comment: The [AWS Signature Version 4](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_define.htm&type=5#content) seems to only help build the endpoint + cryptographically signs the request body.   My hunch is you still need to set the Body with your info like what resources you're trying to `PUT`, etc.